How to integrate $\int\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}dx$ for $n\geq 5$?
How to integrate $$\int\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}dx$$ ? For $n\geq 5$ ?
A simple Approach is:

For $n=1$, the integral is $$\int\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)}dx$$ which results in $x+C$.

For $n=2$, the integral is $$\int\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(x)}dx$$ which results in $2\sin(x)+C$.

Similarly for $n=3$, the integral is $$\int\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(x)}dx$$ which results in $$3x-4\int\cos^{2}(x)dx+C$$. Now $\cos^{2}(x)$ can be written as $\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$ and it can be easily integrated easily.


For $n=4$, the integral is $\int\frac{\sin(4x)}{\sin(x)}dx=\int 4\cos(x)\cos(2x)dx$
Now $2\cos(x)\cos(2x)=\cos(3x)+\cos(x)$ and then we can integrate it easily.
But for $n\geq 5$ , the integral will be quite difficult. Please help me out.
Today I saw that a person asked a question $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\tan(5x)}{\tan(x)}dx$ like that of similar type.

This should work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Multiple-angle_formulae_2

Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an Approach0 search, there are the related Shortest way to integrate and Determine the anti-derivative of $\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}$, where $n$ is an even integer.

$\sin nx = \frac {e^{inx} - e^{-inx}}{2i}$
$\frac {\sin nx}{\sin x} = \frac {e^{inx} - e^{-inx}}{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}$
$\frac {\sin nx}{\sin x} = \frac {(e^{ix} - e^{-ix})(e^{i(n-1)x} + e^{i(n-3)x} + \cdots+ e^{i(1-n)x})}{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}$
$\frac {\sin nx}{\sin x} = 2(\cos (n-1)x + \cos (n-3)x + \cdots + \cos x)$ if $n$ is even and
$\frac {\sin nx}{\sin x} = 2(\cos (n-1)x + \cos (n-3)x + \cdots + \cos 2x) + 1$ if $n$ is odd.
If you have not learned this relationship between the trig functions as complex exponentials, you can take the process in reverse...
$2(\cos (n-1)x + \cos (n-3)x + \cdots + \cos x)$
Multipliply by $\frac {\sin x}{\sin x}$
$\frac {2(\sin x\cos (n-1)x + \sin x\cos (n-3)x + \cdots + \sin x\cos x)}{\sin x}$
Apply the identity $\sin A\cos B  = \frac {\sin (A+B) - \sin (A-B)}{2}$
$\frac {\sin nx - \sin (n-2)x + \sin (n-2)x - \sin (n-4)x + \cdots +\sin 2x -\sin 0}{\sin x}$
